# Chef library other cookbook library dependency

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to write a wrapper cookbook for the Public Aws cookbook in chef. I'm making a recipe which installs the CodeDeploy agent, which can change depending on the region. I've written a couple of libraries to help me do this but I get stuck when the library in my wrapper cookbook depends on a library in the original cookbook. I'm not sure if I need to do a require + include here (and if I do I don't know the path for require).

I have 'depends "aws"' in my metadata.rb file.

How can I set up the dependencies properly so this works? At the moment I get errors like this

```
undefined method `instance_availability_zone' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile
```

Or am I doing this totally wrong?

Here's the library with the problem

```
module Opscode
  module Aws
    module Ec2
      module Region
        # require '?????' # Do I need this?
        # include Opscode::Aws::Ec2 # Do I need this?
        def instance_region
          # query instance region comes from Opscode::Aws::Ec2
          # this is the dependency. 
          # Using Opscode::Aws::Ec2.instance_availability_zone doesn't
          # work either.
          @@instance_region ||= query_instance_region 
        end
        def query_instance_region
          region = instance_availability_zone
          region = region[0, region.length - 1]
          region
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This library works as I know the require path

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'ec2_region')
module Opscode
  module Aws
    module CodeDeploy
      include Opscode::Aws::Ec2::Region
      def codedeploy_region_url
        @@region_url ||= query_codedeploy_region_url
      end
      def query_codedeploy_region_url
        region = instance_region
        codeDeployPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-codedeploy-#{region}/latest/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm"
        codeDeployPath
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the recipe

```
Chef::Resource::RemoteFile.send(:include, Opscode::Aws::CodeDeploy)

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/codedeploy-agent.rpm" do
  source codedeploy_region_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may require with a known path from chef-cache and the known path to the library inside the cookbook.

something like this should do:

```
require File.join(Chef::Config['chef_repo_path'],'cookbooks/aws/libraries/ec2_region')
```

Comment: Thank you, that does seem to work (with ::Config instead of ::config). Is there a better way to do this in general though? It seems funny to fallback on using file paths like regular ruby when Chef has its own structure and way of loading libraries. I thought Chef might have some sort of built in way to find library dependencies, especially for sub modules like this.